# Filtrar Classes Utilizadas e Inutilizadas Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, desempenho

Estou importando o bootstrap para uma Landing Page, porém como o conteúdo é pouco consequentemente as classes que precisei utilizar também são poucas.

Queria saber se tem alguma forma automatizada de filtrar quais classes estou utilizando e gerar um arquivo css com elas, descartando todas as outras classes que não estão sendo utilizadas.

Gostaria de saber também qual impacto de importar as milhares de classes do bootstrap para um documento pequeno que deve usar apenas uma pequena parte dos recursos.

Tem alguma diferença significativa na performance da página?

Comment: No site do Bootstrap há a opção de customizar o arquivo css e js para incluir somente o que você vai utilizar no seu site.

Comment: Só complementando o que o @RaylanSoares disse, basicamente você vai "compilar" um bootstrap customizado usando sass e cia, ai você tira o que é "inutil" para você. Ou se é tão simples assim, nem usa bootrap.